# True or false? $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left((n \mod 4)+\frac{1}{n+1} \right )=\frac{9}{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Is the statement true or false?

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left((n \bmod 4)+\frac{1}{n+1} \right )=\frac{9}{2}$$

No proofs needed, just an answer but I'd like to know the reason, too.

So lim sup means the greatest cluster point of the given sequence, right?

I know that $\frac{1}{n+1}$ will go to **$0$** for $n\rightarrow\infty$ (corrected mistake).

Because I don't see why $n \bmod 4$ added with $0$ should equal $\frac{9}{2}$, I would say that the statement is false.

What do you think about this?

Comment: How to define $3.5 \ mod    \ 4$

Comment: @ZackNi I believe that $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @ZackNi: Probably $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but it should have been stated in the question.

Comment: You made mistake, $\frac{1}{n+1}$ will go to 0 for $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @user21820 Yes that's so strange because sup (n mod 4)  = 3 and the answer gives a fraction.

Comment: How do you know sup (n mod 4) = 3?

Comment: Eh your new limit is even more marvelous. =P

Comment: $n \bmod 4$ has a maximum that it regularly attains, which must hence be the $\limsup$. However, @ZackNi, note that $\limsup$ is not additive.. You cannot simply break into two parts and sum the $\limsup$s.

Comment: @user21820 if one of the two summands converge, you can.

Comment: I suggest: $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}  (n \text{ mod } 4) = 4 $

Comment: 3.5 mod 4 is just an element in $\mathbb{R}/4\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: That's right. But many students anyhow split without justification, just like $\sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$...

Comment: But how do you know its 4? I don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n\bmod 4\le 3$, we have that, for $n>0$,
$$
(n\bmod 4)+\frac{1}{n+1}<4<\frac{9}{2}
$$

Comment: Is there a trick / logic thing that let's me know n mod 4 $\leq$3?
As an example, would you immediately know if n mod 8 > 5?

Comment: @cnmesr By definition, $n\bmod 4\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ if $n$ is integer. If you use the mod operation on real numbers, all you can say is that $x\bmod 4\in[0,4)$, so $x\bmod 4<4$, but it's easy to modify the proof accordingly, just use $x$ sufficiently large so $(x\bmod 4)+1/(x+1)$ is upper bounded by, say, $4+1/10<9/2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are a nice teacher :)

Comment: @cnmesr It's often easier seeing $y$ is not a cluster point of a sequence $(a_n)$, by showing the sequence “stays away from $y$”, for $n$ sufficiently large (that is, for $n>N$, $a_n\notin(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ for a suitable $\delta>0$). Computing *the* limsup can be more difficult.

Comment: Egreg, one last question: I know that n mod 4 < 4 but it could be that n mod 4 $\leq$ 3.9 ? Or impossible?

Comment: @cnmesr If $n$ is supposed to be integer, you have $n\bmod4\le3$. If it is allowed to take any real value, the range is the whole interval $[0,4)$.

Answer (score 2):

> ??? I know that $\frac1{n+1}$ will go to 1 for $n→∞$.

Ermm I don't know that...

The statement is false anyway; $\frac92$ is bigger than a much simpler upper bound of $4$.

Comment: Ups my bad... .

Comment: @cnmesr: Note that to disprove the $\limsup$ all we need is a better upper bound, but to prove the correct $\limsup$ one needs to really work out the $\sup$ of the tail first.

Answer (score 2):

False.

The sequence $$a_n=n \!\!\!\!\!\mod 4+\frac{1}{n+1}$$ does NOT converge, and it
possesses 4 subsequential limits:

$$
a_{4n}=\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0,\quad
a_{4n+1}=1+\frac{1}{n+1}\to 1,\\
a_{4n+2}=2+\frac{1}{n+1}\to 2,\quad
a_{4n+3}=3+\frac{1}{n+1}\to 3.
$$

Answer (score 1):

False, the answer is $3$.

Proof.

$n$ mod $4$ has only four possibilities: $0,1,2,3$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ goes to $0$.